# VS-Code python module imports yellow even though theyre installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qqus.png)All of the modules are imported and have been but now out of nowhere these 3 are showing up yellow and have an error message along the lines of this...
**Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)**

Comment: Your VSCode is probably not pointing at the same interpreter you are using to run your code.

Comment: Make sure VSCode is using the same virtual environment Python interpreter as the one you used to install those modules.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple python environments on your machine, please choose the correct interpreter for vscode.

##### Choose an interpreter:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette
2. search and select **Python:Select Interpreter**
3. Choose the right interpreter

##### There are two ways to solve the problem here:

- 1. Confirm what environment your package is installed in (for example using `pip show ...` command)

     [image]
  2. choose the interpreter for that environment for vscode

     [image]
- 1. Choose an interpreter you want to use for vscode

     [image]
  2. Create a new terminal to activate the selected environment

     [image]
  3. Install the packages you need for this environment in the new terminal

     [image]

Comment: For me, same issue despite I was in the good **venv**. I uninstalled the package previously installed with `pip unstall django-filter` and ran right after `python3 -m pip install django-filter`. Before doing this, `pip freeze > requirements.txt`didn't write correctly my package in the file but doing `python3 -m pip freeze>requirements.txt`did the trick. Now I can see my module in the list. I had have this kind of problem after a **python upgrade** when I upgrades a few months ago  python from v2 to v3. It's surely not the best way to have a stable machine but this workaround worked ... for me.